# Booting from a USB

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to boot from a usb.  I downloaded the iso file to the usb, but I can't seem to get it installed on my computer.  What should I do from here??

Comment: Could you update your question with some more information? How are you trying to install it? Have you tried changing the boot order already? Do you get an error or does the old OS just start as if nothing happened?

Comment: So I downloaded the iso file to my usb with the Unetbootin. The Windows 7 just starts back up if nothing happened.

Comment: Try changing your boot order and put your USB on #1. This can usually be done by pressing F2 or DEL just after you power on your PC and before Windows starts. Newer PCs also have a boot menu to select a boot device once. This is can usually be accesed by F9, F10 or F11. You may have to enable Legacy USB in your BIOS to boot from USB. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: So I got it installed so thank you! But now it's just logging me back into windows. The boot menu says that the ubuntu is the number 1 boot option and windows is the number 2.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: So what if you select Ubuntu? Are you using Legacy BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: I selected it and put it in the number 1 option.  It says that the Legacy BIO is enabled. Is it supposed to give me an option right at the beginning?

Comment: It should. How did you install it? Select the HDD you installed Ubuntu on as #1. It should show a screen for a few seconds where you can choose for Ubuntu or Windows on next reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I find the most reliable thing is to use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Now you have your ISO, install Unetbootin on your platform. Put in the USB stick, start up Unetbootin, browse to your ISO (see "Diskimage" `[...]` at bottom of screenshot), and let Unetbootin do the rest.

[image]

Comment: Unetbootin is fine, but I rather use LILI on Windows and the built-in 'usb-creator' on Ubuntu, because they don't replace the original screen asking for entry method and language.

Comment: @MrVaykadji - LiLi looks nice, but not a solution I've used; OTOH, the "built in" on Ubuntu hasn't worked consistently for me. I've used Unetbootin loads of times, though, without any problems. (You should add an answer, of course - maybe you are as I type. :)

Comment: built-in had troubles on x64 13.10 but worked fine on all x86 systems, and I think it works well in x64 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Unetbootin or WinUSB and make sure you've had selected the USB-port to be the first boot device.

You can run bios while pressing some of specific keys F2/F10/F11  during system post to access the Boot Menu.